# Location from where base image is pulled in Docker

Tags: windows, docker

I am new to Docker and learning to write the docker file. I am on Windows 10. 
In the docker file it says that

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

My question is - what is the location of the base image "microsoft/dotnet:2.2.1-aspnetcore-runtime"? Is this going to pull this from a web location or it is it is the local drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a local image with that name (check by doing docker image ls) it will deploy that image.

if not it will pull it from dockerhub here https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacob. Does hub.docker.com ensure having all images. For example if the dockerfile has FROM microsoft/aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1715  .. how i make sure that hub.docker has that base image with specific version?

Comment: if hub doesn't have that image and you dont have it locally it you will get an error when you try to build. you can pull the image ahead of time if you want to be sure by doing docker pull microsoft/aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1715

Answer (score 2):

yes, by default this is going to pull the image from the docker registry in the web.

`docker.io`

in theory you could also be using a locally hosted registry (if you had it set up beforehand, for example with JFrog).
you would then have to login to your registry via..

`$ docker login localhost:8080` (for example)

..now when you do..

`$ docker pull ...`

..it tries to pull from your local registry.